# In VB.Net How do I use XmlNodeReader with multiple items of the same type?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I wrote the following code:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO

Public Class FormMain

Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Dim ds1 As New DataSet
    ds1 = NewGetRecords()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
    Label1.Text = ds1.Tables(0).TableName
    If ds1.Tables.Count > 1 Then
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds1.Tables(1)
        Label2.Text = ds1.Tables(1).TableName
    End If
End Sub
Public Function NewGetRecords() As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim xd As New XmlDocument
    xd.LoadXml(TextBox1.Text)
    ds.ReadXml(New XmlNodeReader(xd))
    Return ds
End Function

End Class
```

Here is the XML Data I am using (and this works):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ABMDataSets><ABDataSet><OwnerLogin>demo</OwnerLogin><OwnerUniqueID>abcd</OwnerUniqueID><OwnerPassword>abcd</OwnerPassword><OwnerName>Demo Owner</OwnerName><Address1>324 East Wisconsin Avenue</Address1><Address2>Suite 423</Address2><Address3></Address3><City>Milwaukee</City><State>WI</State><Country>US</Country><PostalCode>53202</PostalCode><Phone>414-431-8775</Phone><Email>abcd@efg.com</Email><PayPalAccount>abcd@efg.com</PayPalAccount><PercentMarkup>5</PercentMarkup><JoinDate>2012-01-25 00:57:00</JoinDate><ReferredBy></ReferredBy><Active>1</Active></ABDataSet></ABMDataSets>
```

What doesn't work is when I have multiple records (For example, there are two records similar to the above):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ABMDataSets><ABDataSet><OwnerLogin>demo</OwnerLogin><OwnerUniqueID>abcd</OwnerUniqueID><OwnerPassword>abcd</OwnerPassword><OwnerName>Demo Owner</OwnerName><Address1>324 East Wisconsin Avenue</Address1><Address2>Suite 423</Address2><Address3></Address3><City>Milwaukee</City><State>WI</State><Country>US</Country><PostalCode>53202</PostalCode><Phone>414-431-8775</Phone><Email>abcd@efg.com</Email><PayPalAccount>abcd@efg.com</PayPalAccount><PercentMarkup>5</PercentMarkup><JoinDate>2012-01-25 00:57:00</JoinDate><ReferredBy></ReferredBy><Active>1</Active><OwnerLogin>demo</OwnerLogin><OwnerUniqueID>abcd</OwnerUniqueID><OwnerPassword>abcd</OwnerPassword><OwnerName>Demo Owner</OwnerName><Address1>324 East Wisconsin Avenue</Address1><Address2>Suite 423</Address2><Address3></Address3><City>Milwaukee</City><State>WI</State><Country>US</Country><PostalCode>53202</PostalCode><Phone>414-431-8775</Phone><Email>abcd@efg.com</Email><PayPalAccount>abcd@efg.com</PayPalAccount><PercentMarkup>5</PercentMarkup><JoinDate>2012-01-25 00:57:00</JoinDate><ReferredBy></ReferredBy><Active>1</Active></ABDataSet></ABMDataSets>
```

The first set of data give me a nice table called ABDataset and all the fields are in columns as expected.  It gives me just one table and one record.  The second set of data should give me the same with two records, but instead gives me some 19 or 20 tables with no discernible relationship between field names, column names and values.

Comment: Please explain in detail as to what happens when it "doesn't work". Do you get an error? If so which one exactly for which statement of your code? Does the `xd.LoadXml` give the error? Or the DataSet when you do `ds.ReadXml`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the explanation of the error, have now done that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an extra level that encapsulates each record, I used `<rec></rec>` here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ABMDataSets><ABDataSet><rec><OwnerLogin>demo</OwnerLogin><OwnerUniqueID>abcd</OwnerUniqueID><OwnerPassword>abcd</OwnerPassword><OwnerName>Demo Owner</OwnerName><Address1>324 East Wisconsin Avenue</Address1><Address2>Suite 423</Address2><Address3/><City>Milwaukee</City><State>WI</State><Country>US</Country><PostalCode>53202</PostalCode><Phone>414-431-8775</Phone><Email>abcd@efg.com</Email><PayPalAccount>abcd@efg.com</PayPalAccount><PercentMarkup>5</PercentMarkup><JoinDate>2012-01-25 00:57:00</JoinDate><ReferredBy/><Active>1</Active></rec><rec><OwnerLogin>demo</OwnerLogin><OwnerUniqueID>abcd</OwnerUniqueID><OwnerPassword>abcd</OwnerPassword><OwnerName>Demo Owner</OwnerName><Address1>324 East Wisconsin Avenue</Address1><Address2>Suite 423</Address2><Address3/><City>Milwaukee</City><State>WI</State><Country>US</Country><PostalCode>53202</PostalCode><Phone>414-431-8775</Phone><Email>abcd@efg.com</Email><PayPalAccount>abcd@efg.com</PayPalAccount><PercentMarkup>5</PercentMarkup><JoinDate>2012-01-25 00:57:00</JoinDate><ReferredBy/><Active>1</Active></rec></ABDataSet></ABMDataSets>
```

Or wrap each record in `<ABDataSet></ABDataSet>`

I modified your code a bit to display all the tables one at a time:

```
            Dim miCnt As Integer

            Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
                Dim ds1 As New DataSet
                ds1 = NewGetRecords()
                Dim iTbl As Integer = miCnt Mod ds1.Tables.Count
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(iTbl)
                Label1.Text = ds1.Tables(iTbl).TableName
                miCnt += 1
            End Sub
```

Thanks for your NewGetRecords() code - very nice!

Comment: That makes sense. I wish there was an easier way, because I will have to go and change each record in our database.  But that's my fault - bad/lazy data design.

Comment: BTW, your solution works without having multiple tables - I get multiple rows in just one table.  No change in code, just changing the data format.